# Using parameters in Formula Fields in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Is it possible to use parameters in Formula Fields in crystal report ? 
Somthing like 
SELECT (SELECT SUM(GROSS) FROM InvoiceHeads WHERE DocDate < {?FromDate})
Or how should i manage something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Formula fields don't support SQL statements; use a SQL-Expression field instead.  The resulting query is embedded in the 'main' query:

```
SELECT  table.field_01, table.field_01,
        --SQL Expression
        (
          SELECT SUM(GROSS) 
          FROM InvoiceHeads 
          -- correlated w/ 'main' query
          WHERE DocDate BETWEEN table.date_00 AND table.date_01
        )
FROM    table
WHERE   ...
```

Two caveats:

- the query must return a scalar value
- parameters are NOT permitted

If you need to parameterize your sub-query, you have a two options:

- embed a sub-report; link desired date field; pass data to main report using `Shared` variables
- use a Command object

Comment: thanks craig but i want to display result parameter query i have two parameters in my report from date and to date parameter i want to display like SELECT SUM(GROSS) 
          FROM InvoiceHeads 
                   WHERE DocDate BETWEEN ?fromDate AND ?Todate how to achieve this